# My Camera App is throwing this error: Java.Lang.RuntimeException: start failed

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-camera2, video-recording, java.lang.class

I am developing an app to take short videos using the rear or back camera. I am using the camera2 object in xamarin.android. I am able to select the rear lens and open the camera like below:

```
            // Create an instance of CameraManager
            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.CameraService);

            string cameraId = null;

            // Get the ID of the back-facing camera
            App.cameraId = manager.GetCameraIdList().FirstOrDefault(id => (int)manager.GetCameraCharacteristics(id).Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensFacing) == (int)LensFacing.Back);
          

            // Create an instance of CameraDevice
            CameraDevice cameraDevice = null;
            manager.OpenCamera(cameraId, new MyCameraDeviceStateCallback(this), null);
```

Now, I created an instance of MediaRecorder object and set it up as below:

```
    // Create a new instance of MediaRecorder
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Set the video source to the camera
    mediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);

    // Set the output format and file path
    mediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
    mediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal).ToString() + "/video.mp4");

    // Set the video encoder
    mediaRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);

    // Prepare and start recording
    mediaRecorder.Prepare();
    mediaRecorder.Start();
```

However, anytime I debug the app to mediaRecorder.Start(), I hear a loud sound (from the speakers) and after a second or two the error above pops up.

This is the complete error stack trace:

> - ```
>   $exception  {Java.Lang.RuntimeException: start failed.   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
>   ```
>
> (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
> method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00068] in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11884
> at
> Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod
> (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
> Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00030] in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:66
> at Android.Media.MediaRecorder.Start () [0x00000] in
> /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-33/mcw/Android.Media.MediaRecorder.cs:2440
> at IMEI247_Tracker.Droid.MyBroadcastReceiver2.RecordVideoWithoutAudio
> () [0x0003c] in
> F:\MobileApps\Customized\Others\IMEITracker\IMEITracker.Android\MyBroadcastReceiver2.cs:4346
> at IMEI247_Tracker.Droid.MyBroadcastReceiver2.TakeAVideo3 () [0x000f3]
> in
> F:\MobileApps\Customized\Others\IMEITracker\IMEITracker.Android\MyBroadcastReceiver2.cs:4229
> at IMEI247_Tracker.Droid.MyBroadcastReceiver2.b__18_7 ()
> [0x00005] in
> F:\MobileApps\Customized\Others\IMEITracker\IMEITracker.Android\MyBroadcastReceiver2.cs:520
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object
> state) [0x00014] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:74
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
> (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
> System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00071] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
> (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
> System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
> (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state)
> [0x0002b] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in
> /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:111
> --- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace --- java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.   at
> android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
> } Java.Lang.RuntimeException

I am using a Techno Spark 4 Android 9 phone for testing my app.

So, what is really the issue and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Do you need to set the output files.  Found similar Java code here : https://www.google.com/search?q=android.media.MediaRecorder.start&rlz=1C1RXQR_enUS1075US1075&oq=android.media.MediaRecorder.start&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQABge0gEIMTIxOWowajeoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&bshm=rimc/1

Comment: I think so. I am mailing the recorded content to a server. So, it is a must that I save the video.

Comment: If you don't save to fill it will use lots of memory which may be why you are failing.